# Is there a User interface in window installer for uninstall?

Tags: installation, window, windows-installer

This is complicated to explain and I am trying my best. Sorry in advance.

I have developed a window installer with checkboxes for different window services to be installed. Let say I checked 2 out 3 services to be installed and it installed ok.

My requirement and question is to have some checkboxes of UI to show the services I installed and be able to uncheck the one I do not want to uninstall. is it possible with window installer? or I should develop a window application to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

No. The general approach is to put each service into its own feature and let users "modify" the install to remove individual features. During an uninstall, everything will be removed; there isn't an option for "partial uninstall." But modify lets the user install and uninstall individual features.